# Strictly positive solution to system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I have the following system:
\begin{align}
\left\{
\begin{array}
$21 = 55x_{100} + 54x_{99} + \dots + x_{46} \\
17 = 50x_{100} + 49x_{99} + \dots + x_{51} \\
13 = 45x_{100} + 44x_{99} + \dots + x_{56} \\
20 = 40x_{100} + 39x_{99} + \dots + x_{61} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
Does the system have a solution $x \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ with all its elements strictly positive? I'm stuck in answering this question.

What is the quickest way to answer this question?

Comment: Pairwise subtract equations to remove most of the variables, then use the simplex method. Even if you find an answer with not all of the variables $>0$, but some $=0$, it's fine, since all the variables have positive coefficients (so you can nominally increase the value of the 0 variables).

Answer (score 1):

The question of whether such a solution exists can be formulated as a linear program.

We will introduce an auxiliary variable $t$, which at optimality will satisfy $t=\min\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{100}\}$. We wish to maximize $t$. If $t>0$, then $x_i>0$ for all $i=1,\dots,100$. Otherwise, no such solution exists.

The resulting linear program is
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max&t\\
\text{s.t.}&t\leq{x_i}\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,100\\
&t\leq1\\
&(\text{Your system of equalities here})
\end{array}
$$ 
The constraint $t\leq1$ ensures that the problem isn’t unbounded.